# VBA - Loop through rows and delete if multiple values exists

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to optimize my code which loops through all rows and deletes it if a certain value exists. However, I am currently looping through > 100000 rows, so I wish to improve the speed.

**Main purpose**: Loop through all rows and delete it if **a)** cell(row, "A").value = "X1", **b)** cell(row, "S").value = "X2", and **c)** cell(row, "AW").value = "X3".

My current code is as follows:

```
Call FilterData("A", "X1")
Call FilterData("S", "X2")
Call FilterData("AW", "X3")

Sub FilterData(Column as String, Check as String)
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    If Not Sheets("XXX").AutoFilterMode Then
        Sheets("XXX").Range("1:1").AutoFilter
    End If
    Sheets("XXX").Range("A2:BT1048576").Sort _
    Key1:=Sheets("XXX").Range(Column & "1"), Order1:=xlAscending

    With Sheets("XXX")
        .Select

        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
            With .Cells(Lrow, Column)
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = Check Then .EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next Lrow

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing by applying a autofiler against the columns you wish to delete, if the values exist, the code deletes them. I made this really quickly, untested, but the logic works, hope this helps! :)

Code Added:

```
Sub Filter()
Dim ColALookup As String
Dim ColSLookup As String
Dim colAWlookup As String
Dim i As Long

 ColALookup = "X1"
 ColSLookup = "X2"
 colAWlookup = "X3"

 With Sheets("XXX")
.Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(ColALookup), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    .Range("S2", .Range("S" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(ColSLookup), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    .Range("AW2", .Range("AW" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(colAWlookup), Operator:=xlFilterValues

.Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .Range("S2", .Range("S" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .Range("AW2", .Range("AW" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
.AutoFilterMode = False

 End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I know, I accidently posted it as a answer :(

Comment: I also don't have enough reputation to post a comment unfortunately

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, @Jaz

Comment: @hskrijelj Updated OP to reflect a quick example, hopefully this helps to point you into a easier method

Comment: I'm assuming your First Row is a header row as well in this code :)